# Trouble with named groups in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm playing with django urls.py and have some problems with the named groups syntax

Like this without named groups it works...

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',index),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^',test),    
)
```

but with named groups i have a syntax error, which i can't solve

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',index),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (?P<requrl>r'^',test), # this is new    
)
```

Any help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite obviously a syntax error. For a start, you have most of the characters outside the quote marks, and secondly, the syntax you have for your "named groups" is not even close to correct.

You should read the documentation more closely, followed by an introduction to regular expressions.

```
(r'^(?P<requrl>.*)$',test)
```

Comment: thank a lot! I will teach myself regular expressions and take this as a starting point ;-P

Comment: and to protect me at least a bit...because downvotes are starting...in the django doc there are just examples where named groups are appended to a string...so this was kind of new for me...

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the syntax more closely. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

```
    (?P<requrl>r'^',test), # this is new
```

should be something like

```
    (r'^(?P<requrl>.*)/$',test), # this is new
```